# Design a cold gas ACS nozzle

Tags: propulsion, attitude, nozzle

I have the total thrust required to be F=16.9 KN. I am using nitrogen gas, and the stored temperature in the nitrogen gas cylinder is 155 bars with a temperature of 325k. How would I design the nozzle and determine the exit area, assuming its in space?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the work you have accomplished so far.

Comment: What is an ACS nozzle?

Comment: @RussellBorogove, I think OP means a thruster used for the attitude control. Although 17kN for an ADCS thruster is a crazy high amount!

Comment: Nitrogen gas cools down when expanded rapidly from high pressure.